# TypeScript Should not emit a type ref

Tags: typescript

I keep getting this error when I try to run my TypeScript app:

Should not emit a type ref.
The command `"tsc -target ES5 "app.ts" "test.ts""` exited with code 1.

That's all what I get. Not even the line where it occurs.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Should not emit a type ref" is an internal error that can be thrown by the compiler itself. Usually it's because the compiler failed to recover gracefully from a syntax error in your program, but other times perfectly valid programs can cause this error. In any case, whenever you see this error, it's a bug! Please file a bug on [Codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create), taking care to attach any relevant files we would need to reproduce the issue. See the [Project Guidelines](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guidelines&referringTitle=Home) for information on how to file a bug.

Comment: I've reported it. You can find the report [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/183)